# How can I automatically implement map markers? Wrong connection or wrong code?

Tags: php, android, json, url, google-maps-markers

I struggle with receiving google map markers from MySQL database. 
I have this problem java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference.

Part of my code:

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> location = null;
    try {

        JSONArray data = new JSONArray(RetrieveTask.class);

        location = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map;

        for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

            map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("id", c.getString("id"));
            map.put("lat", c.getString("lat"));
            map.put("lng", c.getString("lng"));
            location.add(map);
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < location.size/*here it shows the problem - size*/(); i++) {
        String id = location.get(i).get("id");
        double lat = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("lat"));
        double lng = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("lng"));
        LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
        MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(id);
        googleMap.addMarker(marker);
    }
```

And code from connecting to the interenet:

```
private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
        String strUrl = "http://12345.php";
        URL url = null;
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        try {
            url = new URL(strUrl);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.connect();
            InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
            String line = "";

            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                sb.append(line);
            }

            reader.close();
            iStream.close();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

}
```

I have no idea what is wrong with my code, I have tried different ways but still got same error.
Has anybody struggled with the same problem before, how did you sort it out?

Might it be database fault because it is not remote, I use localhost?
JSON response works fine, it returns expected values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For sure you got NPE because you catch JSONException

```
catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And you got it because of this line

```
JSONArray data = new JSONArray(RetrieveTask.class);
```

You are not getting data from internet with this line. You just try to create `JSONArray` from `class` object.

You had to use method `onPostExecute` in your `AsyncTask`

```
 protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
     //call here method of Activity or parse your JSONArray
     JSONArray data = new JSONArray(result);
     //your other code
 }
```

Comment: Thank you, just changed my code and now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you aren't following proper procedure to retrieve your data from the localhost. You first need to override the **onPostExecute()** method of AsyncTask and then you should retrieve the resulting data from your localhost in the **onPostExecute()** method.

Your code crashes at this line

```
JSONArray data = new JSONArray(RetrieveTask.class);
```

and hence location isn't initialised yet. So when you try to access location in the next for loop it throws a NullPointerException.

That's how your code should look:

```
private class RetrieveTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

@Override
protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
    String strUrl = "http://12345.php";
    URL url = null;
    StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

    try {
        url = new URL(strUrl);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.connect();
        InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));
        String line = "";

        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line);
        }

        reader.close();
        iStream.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return sb.toString();
}

@Override
protected String onPostExecute(String result){
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> location = null;
try {

    JSONArray data = new JSONArray(result);

    location = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> map;

    for(int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject c = data.getJSONObject(i);

        map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("id", c.getString("id"));
        map.put("lat", c.getString("lat"));
        map.put("lng", c.getString("lng"));
        location.add(map);
    }
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

//the if loop is to check if location is initialised above
if(location!=null){ 
        for (int i = 0; i < location.size/*here it shows the problem - size*/(); i++) {
            String id = location.get(i).get("id");
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("lat"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(location.get(i).get("lng"));
            LatLng latLng = new LatLng(lat, lng);
            MarkerOptions marker = new MarkerOptions().position(latLng).title(id);
            googleMap.addMarker(marker);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Then you could execute the AsyncTask in this way:

```
new RetrieveTask().execute();
```

Here's an example of AsyncTask it'll help you understand proper flow of the same.

[You can skip to Step no. 7 to know about the Android setup for connecting to localhost](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/)

Comment: Thank you, I almost did it the same way.